# div tags - help (dreamweaver html)

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

**new problem**: so I'm using this given index.html with everything in it already, and changing to my needs. Spoke to teacher about changing the li class due to fit the new needs of this app, as per here:

```
 <div id="page" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <div class="logo"><div align="center"><img src="images/logo.png" width="635" height="95"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
            <li class="accom"><a href="#accom"></a></li>
            <li class="dining"><a href="#dining"></a></li>
            <li class="events"><a href="#events"></a></li>
            <li class="entertainment"><a href="#entertainment"></a></li>
            <li class="maps"><a href="#maps"></a></li>
            <li class="attractions"><a href="#attractions"></a></li>
            <li class="transport"><a href="#transport"></a></li>
```

**Question:** for each page now, the original # in the href was called for example who, and the corresponding div tag was "who". Because it's now an li class, and the name has changed, I tried to change the div tag to the new either li class or the a href, in the comments.

This hasn't worked. Anyone got an idea on to how to fix? The div id links to the new pages from the main screen as per code from the beginning.

This is my second post, so sorry if it gets confusing.

Cheers.

Seems as code is not showing - Go here for the code:https://docs.google.com/document/d/10GB52-lO_e-bnupGyiJFISTmH4iWFOixPtnjKcx_WPg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please post a code example? Rather than explaining the html just add the  *relevant* part to your post.

Comment: @wahwahwah try here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10GB52-lO_e-bnupGyiJFISTmH4iWFOixPtnjKcx_WPg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ConfusedDreamweaverUser Please post the code; users should be able to answer your question without going on another website.

Comment: @ConfusedDreamweaverUser -  You mentioned "it hasn't worked.." few times in your post... what  is *it* in this situation? Is the link broken? Have you provided us with html for the broken link? Is there enough information in this post for us to reproduce and/or understand the issue you are having?

Comment: @wahwahwah, it's all good now I've fixed it up.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you wanted to change the location of the link?

When you moved the anchor to inside the `<li>` I bet its width/height is 0/0 and clicking on the `<li>` doesn't do anything.

Set your `<a>` tags to be

```
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

and see if that fixes the issue.

A jsfiddle would really help in this scenario.

Comment: It's more that the <li class = "accom"> etc, does not link up to its own page.